# Abstract interface inheritance

Tags: c++

Must virtual methods be always implemented in derived class? 
Can I write something like this?

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
class BaseInterface 
{
public:
   virtual void fun_a() = 0;
   virtual void fun_b() = 0;
   virtual ~BaseInterface(); 
};

class Derived : public BaseInterface
{
   void fun_a() { ... };
};

class FinalClass : public Derived
{
   void fun_b() { ... };
}

int main()
{
   FinalClass test_obj;
   test_obj.fun_a();  // use Derived implementation or fail ???
   test_obj.fun_b();  // use own implementation 
   BaseInterface* test_interface = new FinalClass();
   test_interface->fun_a(); // fail or ok ???
   test_interface->fun_b(); 
}
```

Is the code above correct?
Does another virtual method `outflank` exist?

Comment: Have a look here at this example: http://liveworkspace.org/code/6huYU$8 It seems to work.

Comment: What doesn't work is this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/6huYU$10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pure virtual methods always must be reimplemented in derived class?

Actually a derived class which is going to be instantiated.

In your code, you didn't make an object from `Derived` so it's OK.

> Can i write something like this?

Yes.

You had some minor errors that I corrected them:

```
class BaseInterface
{
public:
    virtual void fun_a() = 0;
    virtual void fun_b() = 0;

    virtual ~BaseInterface() {};  // You forget this
};

class Derived : public BaseInterface
{
public:
    void fun_a() {}  // This should be public as its base
};

class FinalClass : public Derived
{
public:
    void fun_b() {} // This should be public as its base
};

int main()
{
    FinalClass test_obj;
    test_obj.fun_a();
    test_obj.fun_b();
    BaseInterface* test_interface = new FinalClass();
    test_interface->fun_a();
    test_interface->fun_b();
}
```

Comment: devied class? Or you mean derived class.

Comment: @DeadWarlock: derived. typo.

Answer (score 0):

It makes `Derived` also an abstract class which you cannot instantiate, seeing you don't implement all the `virtual` functions from it's base, it becomes an abstract class you cannot directly instantiate.

See here:  liveworkspace.org/code/6huYU$10

For the rest, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct.
There is no special concept for *interface* in C++. All are classes. Some of the class methods can be pure virtual. It only means that compiler cannot create an instance of such class.